# Copy the result of a selection grouped by into a table

Tags: python, postgresql

Ok, first of all: I am quite new to PostgreSQL and programming in general.
So I have two tables. One table (cars) is:

```
 id |  brand  | model | price 
----+---------+-------+-------
  1 | Opel    | Astra | 12000
  2 | Citroen | C1    | 12000
  3 | Citroen | C2    | 15000
  4 | Citroen | C3    | 18000
  5 | Audi    | A3    | 20000
```

And the other is:

```
 id |  brand  | max_price 
----+---------+-----------
  4 | Opel    |          
  5 | Citroen |          
  6 | Audi    |
```

What I would like to do is, make a selection on cars so that I have the max price grouped by brand and then I would like to insert the price to the correspondent brand in max price.
I tried to use python and this is what I have done:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute ("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp """)
cur.execute ("""CREATE TABLE temp (brand text, max_price integer)""")
conn.commit()
cur.execute ("""SELECT  cars.brand, MAX(cars.price) FROM cars GROUP BY    brand;""")
results = cur.fetchall()
for results in results:
  cur.execute ("""INSERT INTO temp (brand, max_price) VALUES %s""" % str(results))
  conn.commit()

cur.execute ("""UPDATE max_price SET max_price.max_price=temp.max_price   WHERE max_price.brand = temp.brand;""")
conn.commit()
```

It gets stuck in the update part, `signalling an error max_price.brand = temp.brand`

Can anybody help me?

EDIT: thanks to the suggestion of domino I changed the last line with `cur.execute ("""UPDATE max_price SET max_price.max_price=temp.max_price_int from temp WHERE max_price.brand = temp.brand;""")` Now I have the problem that temp.max_price is a recognised not as an integer but as a tuple. So, to solve the problem I tried to add before this last line the following code:

```
for results in results:
results =results[0]
results = int(results)
cur.execute ("""INSERT INTO temp (max_price_int) VALUES %s""" % str(results))
conn.commit()
```

It gives me an error

```
cur.execute ("""INSERT INTO temp (max_price_int) VALUES %s""" % str(results)) 
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "12000"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO temp (max_price_int) VALUES 12000
```

12000 is exactly the first value I want it to insert!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work it says: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: table name "max_price" specified more than once. I tried `    SET max_price.max_price=temp.max_price from max_price, temp WHERE max_price.brand = temp.brand;` but it doesn't work, as well.

Comment: we are making progress, in a sense. Now the mistake is "cannot assign to field "max_price" of column "max_price" because its type integer is not a composite type" which makes sense, because I set it as string... So, I tried the following couple of lines before that one 'cur.execute ("""ALTER TABLE temp ALTER COLUMN max_price TYPE integer USING max_price::integer;""")
conn.commit()' but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `cur.execute`, you should never use the `%` operator.  It opens up your queries to SQL injection attacks.

Instead, use the built-in query parameterization like so:

`cur.execute ("""INSERT INTO temp (max_price_int) VALUES (%s)""",(results,))`

See documentation here:  http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

---

A different approach would be to use SQL to do your update in a single query using the `with` clauses.  The single query would look like this:

```
with max (brand, max_price) as (
  select brand, max(price) from cars
  group by brand
)
update max_price 
   set max_price = max.max_price
from max
where max_price.brand = max.brand
;
```

Read more about Common Table Expressions (CTEs) here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html

Comment: The SQL code works perfectly! Thank you very much! Also, thank you for the reading suggestion! So, I solved my problem. There is still this little thing: I tried to adjust my python code as you suggested but it still gives me exactly the same error message. Still wondering why...

Comment: Looks like it needs parenthesis after `VALUES`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Since you are still new here, may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I tried to vote but I it is not shown because of the reputation but I missed the acceptance part.